# How to select multiple directories with KFileDialog?

Tags: python, linux, qt, kde-plasma, pykde

With `PyKDE4.kio` to select multiple files I can use `KFileDialog.getOpenFileNames` (instead of `KFileDialog.getOpenFileName`). What can I do if I want to select multiple directories? There is only `KFileDialog.getExistingDirectory`.

Using `KFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(filter = 'inode/directory')` and select multiple folders shows an error:

> More than one folder has been selected and this dialog does not accept folders, so it is not possible to decide which one to enter. Please select only one folder to list it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution from [JohannesMunk on qtcentre.org](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/34226-QFileDialog-select-multiple-directories?p=158482#post158482) and translated it to python

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QFileDialog, QAbstractItemView, QListView,
                             QTreeView, QApplication, QDialog)

class getExistingDirectories(QFileDialog):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super(getExistingDirectories, self).__init__(*args)
        self.setOption(self.DontUseNativeDialog, True)
        self.setFileMode(self.Directory)
        self.setOption(self.ShowDirsOnly, True)
        self.findChildren(QListView)[0].setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection)
        self.findChildren(QTreeView)[0].setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection)

qapp = QApplication(sys.argv)
dlg = getExistingDirectories()
if dlg.exec_() == QDialog.Accepted:
    print(dlg.selectedFiles())
```

Comment: could you please add the rest of the code to pop out the filedialog windows?

Comment: @Guillaume et voilà!