# How to Select multiple folders in a directory and display the selected folders python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am new to python ubuntu I am learning , I am doing a small project where I have to select multiple folders in the directory using GUI and print the selected folders. I almost finish other task this is last task which is pending.

Example :

```
Directory A :
    Folder 1;
    Folder 2;
    Folder 3;
    Folder 4;
```

I like to select only `(Folder 1 ; Folder 3; )` And print those names and with path

I got [Select Mutiple folder using Pyqt5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18707261/how-to-select-multiple-directories-with-kfiledialog) But its `Pyt5` , I like to work with `tkinter` or other module.

```
from tkinter import filedialog
dirselect = filedialog.Directory()
dirs = []
while True:
    d = dirselect.show()
    if not d: break
    dirs.append(d)
```

Comment: I believe the right thing to use is `filedialog.askdirectory()`

Comment: I tried , with filedialog.askdirectory(), its not working

Comment: You can able to select only one folder , But I like to select mutiple folders and file.

Comment: Then you might want to use `filedialog.askopenfilenames()` but keep in mind, you cannot mix a folder and file, a file should be chose separately and a folder should be chose separately

Comment: Yes , the problem I am facing. Please chek with link I mentioned, I tried with pyt5 its working perfectly.

Comment: pygt5 and tkinter are not same, i dont tkinter has that feature with it. Try googling it?, or if you want you could ask them twice, one for folder and one for file, and concatenate both the set of items to one main set of items

Comment: You can get the file/dir names using `os.scandir` and insert the results into a `Listbox` with multiple selection enabled.